# I have a timeout to make an ajax call, but chrome keeps on calling it even after the tab is closed

Tags: google-chrome

Normal js code (no service worker, but the app has a manifest with an empty service worker).

A simple timeout to an ajax call that's the code.

I close all chrome tabs, I close the process in task manager, no more chrome processes and yet I still get requests on my server. This happens locally and on the server, I know this because I can see the cookies sent and for which user id is needed.

Also I know that chrome is running the code because there is a date in the request and is updated as it go.

Triple checked that chrome is closed on all users and all processed in task manager.

Is not a coincidence because at this moment I have 2 different users (different chrome profiles) doing this. Also in my dev server there are a lot of users with the same behaviour.

I'm also not sure is chrome, but has to be, node.js alone can't change the time of the request.

Win 10 and Chrome Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Terrible and I don't know what to do...

if I restart my node.js server all the requests stops.

Comment: Try breaking the timeout call on window close.

Comment: Thanks, this might work. But I would also like to understand why this happens exactly?

Comment: This is how JS engine specifications are configured actually. This will continue unless the browser is closed or the process is closed explicitly.

Comment: As stated in the question, all chrome processes have been closed from task manager. Also all chrome windows and logged out from other Windows users.

Comment: Let's wait for someone with more expertise on this. It's beyond my reach.

Comment: thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

Was my mistake! As I have server side rendering (with react) I forgot that the timeout was also run on the server side. The fix was to don't run any timeouts on the server side.

Thanks anyway for the answers. I was concerned how chrome was still running my js code even shut down, made no sense at all!